# Set up multiple session handlers on python webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, webapp2

I'm writing a simple web application in google appengine and python. In this application I need to handle two types of sessions:
the "long term session" that stores information about users, current page ecc, with long max_age parameter and the "short term session" with max_age about 20 minutes that keep an access token for the autentication via API.

I have implemented the following BaseHandler:

```
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import sessions
```

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

`def dispatch(self):
    # Get a session store for this request.
    self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)

    try:
        # Dispatch the request.
        webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
    finally:
        # Save all sessions.
        self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

@webapp2.cached_property
def session(self):
    # Returns a session using the default cookie key.
    return self.session_store.get_session(backend='memcache')

@webapp2.cached_property
def session_auth(self):
    return self.session_store.get_session(backend='memcache', max_age=20*60)<code>`

the problem is that all sessions have max_age=20*60 seconds (and not only the sessions accessible by self.session_auth)..
How should I solve this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your config params:

```
config = {}
config['webapp2_extras.sessions'] = {
    'session_max_age': 100000,   # try None here also, though that is the default
}

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', HomeHandler),
], debug=True, config=config)
```

Comment: I have tried to set the parameter  session_max_age, but this acts on the whole sessions, not only session_auth..

Comment: Yes, but once these are set, you can change session_auth, and the others should remain at your default.