# Set cookie/session that never expires even on browser close using Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session-cookies

I am trying to set cookies to [*never* expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290424/set-a-cookie-to-never-expire) (even after browser has been closed) in Google App Engine using the documentation for [webapp2 sessions](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html#api-webapp2-extras-sessions) and [building a response](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/response.html). I've tried:

**Code snippet 1:**

```
from webapp2
from webapp2_extras import sessions

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def never_expire_session(self):
        sessions.get_session(name='my_session', max_age=2147483647)

    @login_required
    def get(self):
    ....
    html_template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html').render(myapp)
    self.response.out.write(html_template)
```

OR

**Code snippet 2:**

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def never_expire_session(self):
        return self.response.set_cookie('my_session', max_age=2147483647)

    @login_required
    def get(self):
    ....
    html_template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html').render(myapp)
    self.never_expire_session()
    self.response.out.write(html_template)
```

Code Snippet 2 results in a response of `NoneNone`. (Not sure the output of the first code snippet.)

I have also tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335513/set-up-multiple-session-handlers-on-python-webapp2), that recommends configuring the parameters:

```
config = {}
config['webapp2_extras.sessions'] = {'session_max_age': 2147483647}
....
....
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
....
], debug=True, config=config)
```

I've cleared my cookies, restarted my browser, and checked the console and the cookie value shows as a randomly generated sequence of numbers and letters and the expiration of the cookie is set to one year from `datetime.now`. Nothing I've tried works.

How can I correctly set the session cookie so it never expires, even on browser exit?

Comment: What are those first two snippets supposed to be doing? What is calling `never_expire_session`? Why do you switch between cookies and sessions?

Comment: I believe I should be using cookies based on the documentation and Stackoverflow questions I've read so far. But in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684620/is-possible-to-keep-session-even-after-the-browser-is-closed), @jwueller states, "Sessions work with cookies, which are deleted when the browser is closed, unless they have a specific life-time." From my understanding, if I extend session max-age, it will do the same thing as using a cookie? So Code Snippet 1 and  2 are essentially supposed to do the same thing: extend the session max-age. I just don't know which to use.

Comment: Updated code to include where I call `never_expire_session` (in Code snippet 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was experiencing a caching issue which prevented my session cookie from showing in the developer console and being applied. After erasing the browser history and restarting my computer, it cleared the cache. Eventually I got it to work with the following:

```
from webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
         the_value = ''.join(SystemRandom().choice(string.digits _ string.ascii_lowercase) for_in range (50))
         max_age = 2147483647
         # max age for Internet Explorer
         cookie_expires = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta (200)
         return self.response.set_cookie('my_cookie', the_value, max_age=max_age, httponly=True, secure=True)
```

NOTE: if you want to apply this change to a specific cookie, rename "my_cookie" to that cookie (i.e. "*SACSID*" a cookie on many Google applications)

Answer (score 0):

We can even do this using `webapp2_extras.sessions`, no need for `response.set_cookie(...)`. There's a default_config dictionary in webapp2_extras.sessions, just set the max_age to 2147483647 or whatever time (in seconds) works for you, it should work. Worked in my case. Look over the [official documentation](https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html) for more info about default_config.

```
sessions.default_config['cookie_args']['max_age'] = 2147483647
```